# Android Test Case non Activity class

Tags: android, junit

I have a problem to test my non activity-class  which need the context of a activity class.

The class Card extends ImageView and have a few methods:

```
public class Card extends ImageView { 

    public Card(Context context, int cardID) {
       super(context);
       this.cardID = cardID;
       this.turnback = 0;
       backImage =  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backimage);
       setBackgroundDrawable(backImage);
   }
}
```

I would like to test this class as a standalone class, is there an opportunity to create an Dummy Context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no.  The reason being that you are extending a view.   The only way to test a view is to view it.  To do that you need an activity.  This is android fundamentals.